# How to submit form if it has specific and optional text inside value?

Tags: jquery, input, submit

According to jquery documentation I  can do this:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( $( "input:first" ).val() == "correct") {
    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
    return;
  }

  $( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But the question is: 
If value has optional words to validate submit, for example, it can ALSO consist of "ok", "good". How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( ["correct", "ok", "good", "whatever"].indexOf($( "input:first" ).val().toLowerCase())!= -1) {
    $( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
    return;
  }
```

Make an `array` of all the possible values and then check whether the value exist in the `Array` or not. I have added an extra `.toLowerCase` to assure that `OK == ok`

Comment: Perfect! The best way it could even be! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand you but how about

```
if( $.inArray( $( "input:first" ).val(), ['correct', 'ok', 'good'] ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

var txt =   $( "input:first" ).val();
if (txt.indexOf( "yes")>=0 ||txt.indexOf( "ok") >=0){show validated ...